# what is the maximum size of a document in Realtime database in firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a more complicated database where I a want to store lots of data, the issue with fire store is the limit to 1MB per documents, and I am splitting my data in to different document but still according to my calculation the size will be bigger than the limit, yet I cannot find the limit for the Realtime database, and I want to be sure before switching to it, my single document in some cases could hit 6-9mb when scaling big.... at first I want to go with mongodb but I wanted to try the google cloud services.. any idea if the do size is same for both Realtime and firestore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents are part of Firestore (that have 1 MB max size limit each) while Realtime Database on the other hand is just a large JSON like thing. You can find limits of Realtime database in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits).

| Property | Limit | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Maximum depth of child nodes | 32 | Each path in your data tree must be less than 32 levels deep. |
| Length of a key | 768 Bytes | Keys are UTF-8 encoded and can't contain new lines or any of the following characters: . $ # [ ] / or any ASCII control characters (0x00 - 0x1F and 0x7F) |
| Maximum size of a string | 10 MB | Data is UTF-8 encoded |

There isn't a limit of number of child nodes you can have but just keep  the max depth in mind. Also it might be best if you could share a sample of what currently takes over 6 MB in Firestore and maybe restructure the database.